# While attaching a .mdf file in SQL Server i got "non release version(539), not supported by this version" error. how to resolve it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attach database failed for Server 'user'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Database 'jiaowu' cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (539) is not supported by this version of SQL Server. You cannot open a database that is incompatible with this version of sqlservr.exe. You must re-create the database.
>   Could not open new database 'jiaowu'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 950)

Please help me.....

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you trying to attach this `.mdf` to?? The DB version **539** stands for SQL Server **2000**, and this is a very very old version, and it's **no longer supported** in SQL Server 2012 and newer

Answer (score 2):

The version 539 shows that you are using the SQL Server 2000 and it is not supported in SQL Server 2012.

Please refer: [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.105).aspx)

As far as the workaround is concerned you need to first link your SQL Server 2000 to the SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 and then take the backup and then attach it to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Which **version** of SQL Server are you trying to attach this `.mdf` to??

The DB version **539** stands for SQL Server **2000**, and this is a very very old version, and it's **no longer supported** in SQL Server 2012 and newer.

In that case, you'd need to attach your `.mdf` to a SQL Server **2008** or **2008 R2** first, then take a backup and then restore that `.bak` in SQL Server 2012 or newer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to attach the demo .MDF to an older server in order to use in a newer server.

I downloaded the Northwind and pubs Sample Databases [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms143221(v=sql.105)).

The package comes with two SQL scripts named instnwnd and instpubs

You do a little change in each script to create the database and data from scratch:

--Comment the following three lines

--exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','trunc. log on chkpt.','true'

--exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','select into/bulkcopy','true'

--GO

-- and Add the following three lines

```
ALTER DATABASE Northwind    
SET RECOVERY Simple    
GO
```

You run it and will work without issue. The details can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn6FdZ2UGps)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.